# OnMouseUp on a child object of an FPSController [Unity 3d]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an FPSController with a child object, this object is defined as a child because it's supposed to move together with the player as he walks. I then put a script with onMouseUP() on this object, and a box collider component on it, with this simple code:

```
public void OnMouseUp() {
    Debug.Log("It works");

}
```

When I click on it, it won't do anything. If I remove the object from being a child of the FPSController, click works normally. What could be going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Rigidbody component to this child object, the OnMouseUp() will work.

As far as I know, the parent rigidbody is the only one that gets any calls when a child collider is clicked on, unless you give it its own rigidbody or move it out of the hierarchy.

Comment: Good/and very simple solution.. I had to add a kinematic rigid body to it

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

a) your class extends from MonoBehaviour

b) Physics.queriesHitTriggers is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work using raycast, onMouseUp just won't work, I would appreciate a solution that works with it, in case it could be needed for onMouseEnter or any other "OnMouse" trigger.

With the raycast, I had to check for the hit.collider.transform.name to actually get the child object's name, using just hit.transform.name will return the parent name.